# Jquery 'each' does not applicable on ajax loaded dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to refresh google advertisement, which is inside a div. I have added a common css class named 'adslot' for all those div. Few divs loads by ajax. But at document ready, when I call all those div's by jquery each function, it is applicable for only those divs, which has loaded before ajax call.
For example, if give the number of available '.adslot', that is

```
alert($('.adslot').length);
```

output: 5, which is correct. 3 of those divs generated before ajax call, and 2 of those generated after ajax call.

At the same this, if I write -

```
$('.adslot').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

I only get the alert of 1st 3 divs id, which was generated before ajax call.

Has there any way to read all 5 divs ids with jquery?

Comment: wrap the code in ajax success. everything should fall in place then

Comment: You can just use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: or put the code inside a function and call it once in $(document).ready() and once in your ajax success.

Comment: That's because he first _A_ in _AJAX_ stands for _Asynchronous_

Comment: What if you do alert($('.adslot').length); just before $('.adslot').each(function() { ?

Comment: you can add async : false, to your ajax call to stop it from being asynchronous - this will stall page until finished though.

Answer (score 1):

Try your code in `success callback` like

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:....,
        data:...,
        success:function(data){
            $('.adslot').each(function() {
                var id = this.id;
                alert(id);
            });
        }
    });
});
```